# Eclipse Text Search, automating loop over a list of search terms?

Tags: java, eclipse, search, macros, automation

I'm using Eclipse to do a text search on a Java Application. The list of references / search terms are stored procedures (SP). My goal is to see if these SP are being called in  the Java App. I have 50 items, I was hoping if there's a better way of doing this because at the moment my workflow is:

1. select word from List, then push Ctrl-H (Open Text Search)
2. Click enter
3. Record the resultset if any

Is there any way to do this more efficiently? I'm pretty sure I will doing this in the near future again. I've considered using Java, write a small code that reads through the App in the filesystem, looking at the .java files recursively. But I doubt if that will be actually fast enough as the App has many files.

Comment: I think you can try to find a plugin to complete it.Actually step 1 and step 2 can be combined. Select the word you want to search, the press `Ctrl+H`.

Comment: hey good point! thanks for that, saves me alot of handwork with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would search by regular expression (checkbox in a search dialog) for the following string: SP_NAME1|SP_NAME2 (the search terms delimited by |). I make such strings using regexp too.

Comment: This is very helpful! I can easily concatenate my list of search terms and delimit each by | via a simple main. My only 'nice to have' is for the Eclipse result set to segregate the result according to the match, for example SP_NAME1 has its on resultset, the next resultset belongs to SP_NAME2 and so on. But I can live with the current 'mixed' resultset for now. :D