# Easiest, simplest, and fastest way to search within the eclipse workspace from a list of thousands of search strings?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, search, automation

**Additional requirements**:

- It would be nice to save the search result for every search term. It would be even nicer to only save a certain result if certain strings are found in the search result
- I am only interested in searching through *.java, *.xsd, and *.xml file extensions within the workspace

**Notes:**

- There is a good chance that I will need to do this in the future
- The search terms exist in a text file
- I have seen a similar question asked but there were a limited number of answers and they did not answer this question. See [Eclipse Text Search, automating loop over a list of search terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516782/eclipse-text-search-automating-loop-over-a-list-of-search-terms)
- The eclipse project is massive with many nested directiories, so recursion could take a very long time.
- The eclipse workspace (codebase/directory) exists in my C:/DEV directory

**Some pseudo code:**

```
for (searchTerms)
  Find matches
  If match is found
    If match contains certain string
      save this match
```

Maybe there are tools out there that can do this?

Comment: Reading a file is expensive, so the outer loop should not be `for (searchTerms)`. Would it be possible to make a regular expression from all search terms and do a normal file search on the specified files?

Comment: No, can't use regex because every search term is different. It's okay that it is expensive because it would serve as a tool for personal use/help.